# Encryption with same parameters need different results

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to encrypt a string passing the same parameters, but each time it produces the same result.

Currently, each time I call `Encrypt("testing")`, I am getting an output of "pvsLPLnR3fI=". However, I require the output to be different even if the parameters are the same. For example, calling `Encrypt("testing")` 3 times could produce output of:

> pvsLPLnR3fI=
>
> nR3fIasweds=
>
> PHQHasfdevw=

The method I use to encrypt is as follows:

```
private const string mysecurityKey = "MyTestSampleKey";

public static string Encrypt(string TextToEncrypt)
{
    byte[] MyEncryptedArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextToEncrypt);

    MD5CryptoServiceProvider MyMD5CryptoService = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] MysecurityKeyArray = MyMD5CryptoService.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mysecurityKey));

    MyMD5CryptoService.Clear();

    var MyTripleDESCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

    MyTripleDESCryptoService.Key = MysecurityKeyArray;

    MyTripleDESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

    MyTripleDESCryptoService.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    var MyCrytpoTransform = MyTripleDESCryptoService.CreateEncryptor();

    byte[] MyresultArray = MyCrytpoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(MyEncryptedArray, 0, MyEncryptedArray.Length);

    MyTripleDESCryptoService.Clear();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(MyresultArray, 0, MyresultArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Encryption is deterministic; given the same parameters it will always output the same result.  This is a good thing, otherwise the message could not be decrypted!  If you want the same message to encrypt differently then you need to provide something different each time you encrypt.  You could use CBC mode with an IV for instance.  A different IV will give you a different encryption at the cost of a longer cyphertext.  Pick a different IV for every message encrypted with a given key, which is good practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the same result each time because there are no elements of the operation that are changing - you're using the same key and the same plaintext with the same algorithm.  This is expected under the ECB mode of operation.

ECB is inherently insecure, so changing the mode to something like GCM (or CBC if you cannot) will both solve your original problem and improve the security immensely.

Be aware that MD5 and TripleDES are both poor choices for new software - consider using AES with a KDF that isn't a message digest, like Argon2 or PBKDF2.

I suggest you review the code examples in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) for examples of secure, modern encryption.

Comment: Thanks. CBC mode worked and give different output as I needed. But now while decryption that start giving error: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Comment: @AdityaSharma Did you research how CBC mode works and how to implement it correctly?  You can't just swap them out.